# Joining tables on substrings

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I have two database tables called **cars** and **boats**. In both tables I have a column called *country*.

In the **cars** table, *country* is stored like this: `SE:SV:Sweden:Sverige`.

In the **boats** table, *country* is stored like this: `Sweden:SWE:01`.

I need to somehow join these tables on the substring `Sweden`. How would I go about doing that? A trigger? Or can I add new column to each table and do somekind of operation in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design is seriously suboptimal, because you are storing multiple points of data as colon-separated data points in a single column.  That being said, if you must proceed with this design, you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM cars c
INNER JOIN boats b
    ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.country, ':', 1) =
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.country, ':', -2), ':', 1);
```